# Unix filesys reserved space

Tags: filesystems, disk-usage

I've read that in Unix, you can configure the file-system to reserve certain amount of space for root. Which configuration property is it?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why

Comment: What type of filesystem? [ext3, ext4, reiserfs, ...] Use `df -T` to see your filesystem type

Answer (score 0):

If you meant /root as the directory then, you would need to create a new partition on the hard drive with fdisk or parted and assign it to be mounted as /root in either during install process or manually in /etc/fstab file. This way the mount point /root will be consuming just that partition.

along this how to will suffice.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/154180/how-to-mount-a-new-drive-on-startup