# No GUI, disk full, broken system after updating sources

Tags: disk-usage, devices, disk

I have a recent install of Debian 8, with xfce.

All was fine, until I implemented [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/382101/384451), because I wanted to get a more updated package from testing. As suggested there, I created the `.list` files.

After completing that procedure, I run a `sudo apt-get update`. There was an error, which I cannot remember precisely. But the update got stuck at `(98%) [Waiting for headers] [Waiting for headers]` or something like that.

Then, I decided to restart. After logging in , I got:

> Xsession: warning: unable to write to /tmp: Xsession may exit with an error

After a few attempts logging in, I restarted again. Then, the GUI did not appear; there was an error - "tty7 does not exist".

Then, I logged in into tty1, and typed `start`. A screen full of errors appeared, including many `(EE) Fatal server error` and `Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-close.c: 762: _dl_close: Assertion map->l_init_called failed!`

Then, I attempted to install lightdm, as some forums suggest. If I run with root, I get the error:

```
Bus errorackage lists... 1%
```

If I run with sudo, I get:

```
E: Write error - write (28: No space left on device)
E: Can't mmap an empty file
E: Failed to truncate file - ftruncate (9: Bad file descriptor)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Running the command `df -h`, I get that `/dev/sda1/` is used entirely (100%, 9.1G).

I have tried cleaning the cache, the `/var/log` folder, and the `/tmp` folder, as many posts indicate, but no progress.

Additionally, if I use Tab to autocomplete folders or files, I get:

> bash: cannot create temp fil for here-document: no space left on device

Any idea how to proceed?

PS: additionally, I got several screen flashes, changing from black to gray to white... while I am in a tty console.

Comment: Please take a look [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165427/cant-login-due-disk-space-exhaustion/165433#165433)

Comment: Well, the problem was really of low space. I thought Debian space allocation was like that of Ubuntu. I installed heavy things in `/usr/local`, which made the `/` quite heavy. I had to reinstall to reallocate space.

Comment: @luchonacho I hope you used `LVM` when you did the re-install. LVM is an awesome tool that can help you when faced with these problems. A simple livecd reboot (using [systemrescuecd] (http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) can drop you to an environment when you can extend your partitions and filesystems, obviating a need to do a re-install.

Answer (score 1):

Your disk is full. Many programs can't cope.

To at least allow the creation of temporary files, make `/tmp` an in-memory filesystem. That's a good idea anyway: files in `/tmp` don't need to be saved across restarts so they don't need to be on disk. While you repair your system, just mount it manually:

```
mount -t tmpfs -o mode=1777 /tmp
```

Now you'll be able to start the GUI. Either it'll start automatically (those flashes were the display manager attempting to start and failing) or you can run `startx` after logging in to start a GUI session.

There's a reserved quota of space for root, which is 5% by default. If your disk was chock full, you'll need to free more than 5% to allow your account to write to the disk. It's a good idea not to go beyond 95% anyway as performance decreases with near-full filesystems.

Depending on your constraints, you can either delete things you don't need (old logs, old downloaded packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, possibly other things under `/var/cache`, uninstall software that you don't use, …) or enlarge the system partition. Don't remove things if you aren't sure what they do.