# Stuck in commandline login mode in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I've had problems accessing internet so I rebooted my computer.
However, after the reboot, I could only log in in a commandline kind of manner, the GUI is gone.

I typed `df -Th`, which returns:

```
Filesystem Type     Available Used% Mounted on
udev       devtmpfs 7.8G      0%    /dev
tmpfs      tmpfs    1.6G      2%    /run
/dev/sda1  ext4     5.2G      99%   /
tmpfs      tmpfs    7.8G      0%    /dev/shm
tmpfs      tmpfs    5.0M      1%    /run/lock
tmpfs      tmpfs    7.8G      0%    /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop2 squashfs 0       100%    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/loop4 squashfs 0       100%    /snap/gtk-common-themes/1513
/dev/loop0 squashfs 0       100%    /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop6 squashfs 0       100%    /snap/core/10958
/dev/loop3 squashfs 0       100%    /snap/core/10908
/dev/loop5 squashfs 0       100%    /snap/core18/1997
/dev/loop7 squashfs 0       100%    /snap/cloudcompare/205
/dev/loop1 squashfs 0       100%    /snap/cloudcompare/208
tmpfs      tmpfs    1.6G      0%    /run/user/1000
```

I tried deleting some files with `rm` and `sudo rm` but an error occurs saying filesystem is in only accessible in read mode. I tried `chmod +x` with the same error.

I tried `mount -t tmpfs -o mode=1777 /tmp` in sudo mode (suggested here: [no-gui-disk-full-broken-system-after-updating-sources](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321433/no-gui-disk-full-broken-system-after-updating-sources)), reply:
mount: can't find /tmp in /etc/fstab

When I try `startx`, the first lines go too quickly for me to read but I get those error lines at the end of the output:

```
Fatal server error: Could not create lock file in /tmp/.tx0-lock
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/name/.Xauthority
```

When trying `sudo apt-get update`, the computer cannot resolve security.ubuntu.com, extras.ubuntu.com, archive.canonical.com and fr.archive.ubuntu.com.

Am I using too much disk space for the GUI?
Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mount -o remount,rw /` should get you a read/write filesystem allowing you to clear some space.