# Resize2fs doesn't extend my file system to the size of the partition

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, resize2fs

I have a 1 TB hdd but when I run df -h my root partition is only 888G big.Parted -l shows the following

```
3      32.2GB  1000GB  968GB   primary               raid
```

mdstat shows this

```
md2 : active raid1 sdb3[1] sda3[0]
  945363832 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

But when I run resizefs it reports that the filesystem is full and can't be enlarged as follows.

```
sudo resize2fs  /dev/md2
resize2fs 1.42.9 (4-Feb-2014)
The filesystem is already 236340958 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Any ideas how to get around this? I really need the rest of the hdd for backups.

Comment: What fs you are trying to resize , filesystem type?

Comment: The fs is ext4.

Comment: What's the output of `df` (without -h)?

Comment: Umount it first , then run the resize command and the reboot the box , and then report the size by df -h

Comment: 1K Blocks
`/dev/md2       930398424 797672312  85441540  91% /`
4K Blocks
`/dev/md2       232599606 199418144  21360319  91% /`
So, with 4K blocks it more or less adds up to resize2fs output.

Comment: @IjazKhan I can't unmount it, it's and I don't have access to a bootable CD. I have restarted it though to check if the blocksize is cached.

Comment: ok , check the size after restart

Comment: This data is all after the restart

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong here.

- Parted shows a size of 968 gigabytes.
- resize2fs says the filesystem is 236340958 blocks big.
- One block is 4096 bytes
- 236340958 * 4096 = 968052563968
  So, exactly 968 gigabytes.

The confusing thing: `df` shows you gibibytes, not gigabytes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte).

- 968 GB = 901 GiB

The last 13GB can be attributed to filesystem overhead

Edit:

- other filesystems, e.g. XFS, have less filesystem overhead
- if you need more space as non-root, see [Reserved space for root on a filesystem - why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why). But also read the warnings!