# reserve disk space before rsync copying files

Tags: linux, files, rsync, disk-usage, file-copy

**tl;dr** I would like to reserve (or "claim"?) some amount of disk space before an `rsync` occurs so other `rsync` instances will only run if the disk space needed will certainly be available.

### background

A job (a shell script that runs `rsync`) will:

1. Use `rsync` to copy large amount of data from a source disk to a different destination disk
2. do some work using the copied data
3. remove the copied data

Multiple instances of the job script may run simultaneously.

In my case, once in a while, **many job scripts simultaneously `rsync` and use all available disk space. All of the `rsync` instances fail (and so the jobs fail).**

### pseudo-code

Here is the algorithm I'm imagining:

```
$job = get_next_incoming_job()
$disk_dst = $job.disk_dst()  # destination disk for rsync
$space_need = $job.calculate_space_needed()

_check_space:  # jump label

if $space_need > space_available($disk_dst) then
    sleep $RANDOM
    goto _check_space:

$handle = reserve_space($disk_dst, $space_need)  # How??

# rsync will "fill-in" the reserved space - How??
rsync $job.source_data_path() $disk_dst/$job.ID/

do work using $disk_dst/$job.ID/

remove $disk_dst/$job.ID/
release_reserved_space($handle)  # How??
```

The magic function `reserve_space` would instantly change the `$disk_dst` reported free space (value returned by `space_available`). Other `rsync` job instances would see `space_available()` return less space *right away* (and thus, delay their work until later).

Currently, `space_available()` (via actual program `df`) will return a declining number while `rsync` instances run.  The problem is multiple `rsync` instances can run out of space while running.  I'd like the `rsync` instances to only run when it is certain they can complete (i.e. not run out of disk space while running).

Comment: at a high level, I would suggest using some sort of communication mechanism between your scripts (say in a shared file); use locking on the file, and write the actual minus expected space available before the rsync; run the rsync, then  add your used space back it when you're done. new runs of the script then check the "fake available" bytes in the shared file.

Comment: I guess you could somehow sync the filenames and their sizes, create "empty" files that match the final size, then do an rsync...

Answer (score 2):

If you stick to filesystem-independent tools, I can't think of a way to do this other than actually allocating the disk space, i.e. `reserve` would need to create a (non-sparse!) file of the requested size, and you'd need to delete this file before starting `rsync`.

If the files are on an ext2/ext3/ext4 volume and using root access for some operations is acceptable, you can use its [reserved space](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why) feature. The reserved space is normally for root, but you can make it available to a different user or to a different group instead. Run the rsync process as that user/group and adjust the reserved space with [`tune2fs -m`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tune2fs.8.html) before running rsync.

There's probably a more flexible solution with ZFS or Btrfs pools but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

quota and related tools is one way to accomplish that.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/quota

lvextend and friends is another option

https://linux.die.net/man/8/lvextend

Comment: How might that work? What assumptions are you making?