# Reserved-blocks issue: partition size successfully changed but not recognized by the OS

Tags: filesystems, partition, disk-usage, gparted

I run a dual-boot system, and the Linux distro is Ubuntu 14.04.

I have used GParted to enlarge a logical partition, named `/dev/sda6`, on which the `/home` directory is normally mounted. According to the GParted report the operation has been completed successfully. The partition is 85 GiB large, of which 83GiB used and 2 GiB free(d), as intended.

However this comes about with two oddities:

1. This gain is not recognized after logging in. 
   As I check the disk usage with `df -h`, the report says that the partition `/dev/sda6`, duly mounted on `/home`, has a size of 85 GiB, of which 83 are used and **0** are available. The use is claimed to be 100%.
2. Another oddity is that I can regularly log into my user profile through the graphical user interface. After the credentials are recognized, though, the system stalls and it doesn't splash into the desktop environment. 
   In order to get the `df -h` information, I need log in either with my regular identity in any text terminal or with the guest status in the graphic user interface. As a side remark, it doesn't look like data have been corrupted.

How can I fix this situation? The aim is to get the size increase of the partition fully available to the operating system. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: After having fixed this situation (see below), I can confirm that oddity 2 was a consequence of oddity 1, that is shortage of reserved space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using one of the `ext` filesystems (the default linux filesystem, usually `ext4`). Most of the time, when created, it will be created with a specific buffer called `reserved blocks`.
This reserved space is meant to be only writable by system processes and root and therefor protect the OS from the disk filling by users.

The main purpose of `df` is to show the amount of disk space available out of a grand total. While it also shows the space used (by user), it doesn't do so with this reserved space.

This buffer is by default 5% of the whole disk. You can check if you have such a buffer with `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda6 | grep Reserved`. 
By typing `sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda6 | grep [bB]locks` one can also read both the number of reserved blocks and the block size (in B), hence determine the space of the partition taken up by this construction.
This would explain the system seeing 85GiB, but only 83 used and 0 free.

If you really want, you can set the buffer to a lower value with `sudo tune2fs -m 2 /dev/sda6` (2 being an example value in percentage, which by default would be 5).

The better option would be to actually resize so enough disk space is free to be safe. 2GiB of 85GiB is only 2,35%, which isn't a lot and in most cases would fill up relatively fast. If you are sure your space usage will stay stable at 83GiB, then you can use tune2fs to reserve 0% of space for safety, but as soon as your disk fills up then (to 85GiB), you will not be able to log in at all and the machine will probably crash and be harder to repair.

The 5% safety margin is a relatively sane one. So, in this case, I'd make the partition at least 90GiB, but probably even 100 or more, just to have some space to spare for emergencies. Disk space is cheap, your time repairing the problems stemming from a filled-up disk is probably more expensive.

The answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why) give some more insight into the reasoning.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Would you please expand on the opening "the better option would be to actually resize so enough diskspace is free to be safe"?

Comment: I've extended the answer with some rationale.

Comment: Thanks. Using `tune2fs -l` on another computer I could ascertain that the `Reserved block count` (5921408) is 5% of `Block count` (118428160). Since the block `Block size` is 4096 (4 KiB), the reserved space is 22.6 GiB. The information on the same partition from `df -h` is `/dev/sda8 445G 55G 367G 14% /home`. Apparently 445 (size) = 55 (used) + 367 (available) + 23 (reserved) within round-off error. It makes perfect sense.

Answer (score -1):

In order to frame better the situation, some linguistic confusion should be cleared out. **GParted**, **df** and **tune2fs** use same or similar words for slightly different notions concerning disk space.

I rewrote my understanding in terms of pseudo-equations and overloaded these operators:

```
'=' means 'corresponds to'
'@' means 'according to'
```

I started off using `df -h` and leave this understated farther on. Note that `tune2fs -l`, subject to appropriate syntax, normally returns block counts as well as the block size. By multiplying the one by the other, one gets the disk space size. Make sure that disk space measures are expressed in the same base (either 2 or 10).

Firstly, taking the viewpoint of **GParted**

```
size @ gparted = size @ df = block count * block size @ tune2fs
unused @ gparted = free blocks * block size @ tune2fs 
used @ gparted = used @ df = (block count - free blocks) * block size @ tune2fs
```

It is pretty intuitive so far.

Then, taking the viewpoint of **df**

```
size @ df = size @ gparted = block count @ tune2fs 
used @ df = used @ gparted = (block count - free blocks) *block size @ tune2fs
available @ df = max[(free blocks - reserved block count) * block size @ tune2fs, 0]
```

Therefore, **available**@`df` means something different from **free**@`tune2fs` and **unused**@`gparted`.

In summary, the available space in `df` measures the **excess** of the total space, said to be free in `tune2fs` or unused in `gparted`, over the quota reserved by tune2fs. When this excess is zero, it indicates a shortage of the disk space kept aside for good functioning.

Comment: this seems to overcomplicate the issue a bit. your problem was reserved space, plain and simple

Comment: @madeddie I had changed the title of the post to highlight your point. I do agree that the second answer is elaborate but it does not aim to shift the attention away from the reserved blocks issue. I will improve the form as the chance arises. Every user can edit the text for inaccurate content in this meantime.

Comment: yes, mostly the "not recognized" is false, since it's recognized fine, it's just not enough free space :) your answer is mostly about syntax of the language to use while discussing the issue

Comment: @madeddie Please feel free to improve the terminology, by all means. The answer aims to help *recognize* the issue. It is for users who bump in the problem trusting the information from `df`without knowing how it relates the reports from gparted or tune2fs. After you recognise, you can then discuss IMHO.

Comment: @madeddie I have re-edited the content of my answer. Would you please revise whether this may help novices to the topic find their way?

Comment: I think you're making it more complex then it needs to be. There is just some space reserved which you cannot use, but this is not shown in actual disk usage output. I guess your description is correct, but it isn't going to help most people with the "problem".

Comment: @madeddie Thanks. I will take your remarks in consideration for future postings.