# unused space in my filesystem diskspace on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-disk, disk-usage, disk

I have installed ubuntu on my machine alongside with windows, I allocated 55GB for it. After a period, I decided to rise the space allocated to UBUNTU to 60 GB. after this augmentation (using `gparted`) I found that there is a non accessible space in this partition I can't found the problem. The `df -h` command shows me:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             3868944         8   3868936   1% /dev
tmpfs             776332      1240    775092   1% /run
/dev/sda5       60057700  55396248   1587616  98% /
none                   4         0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             3881640       536   3881104   1% /run/shm
none              102400        52    102348   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb1      488384000 464704372  23679628  96% /media/salah/LaCie
```

the `sudo fdisk -l` shows :

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x26464dec

Device    Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      206847      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          206848   409806847   204800000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       409806848   829968383   210080768    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       850939904   976771071    62915584    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       850941952   973240319    61149184   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       973242368   976771071     1764352   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

the properties of the computer disk (the root filesystem) shows me:
 [image: / properties]

As I can I see, the total capacity is not shown in the used and the free space.

Is that problem resulting from changing the partition capacity? Thanks

Comment: As a side note I would look at setting us Ubuntu or any other Gnu/Linux with two partitions one for `/` and one for `/home`. This will allow you to separate you data from the operating systems data. This will help if you ever need to change disro, or if an upgrade fails.

Comment: [Don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text)

Comment: I think the size is usable size, but the filesystem uses some space to manage it self. An example if this if for directory structure and file meta data.

Comment: @richard I've tried to resizing the partition to its original size (55GB) I found that the grey space disappeared. I think that If it is true this space remains even I reduce the size.

Comment: `df` shows only free space of mounted partitions. Either you enlarge the root partition, or add a new partition which needs to be formated and mounted (in `/etc/fstab`). If you calculate 60GB in a base of 1000 it's actually 58,59GB since a GB. is actually 1024 MB - 60GB are 61.440MB ... My guess is that the `df` cmd shows data in a 1024 base and the graphical thing (properties of the computer disk) shows it on a 1000 base

Comment: @MichaelD. I am totally agree with you that a GB is 1024MB and its result, but my question is, where the difference (61.5 - (56.7 + 1.7)=3.1 )   has gone (the grey space)?

Comment: @Slh47 could this be your swap partition?

Comment: @MichaelD. Unfortunately no, the swap partition has only 2GB. and I verified that it is a separated partition with gparted.

Comment: Did you extend the partition without extending the volume to fill it? I.e. the gray is unformatted sectors not part of the ext4 filesystem.

Comment: @jiggunjer The gparted shows that the hole partition is formatted as ext4. is that any other possible way to confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The missing (grey) space in your diagram is the 5% that is reserved by your filesystem.

- 5% of 61.5GB = 3.1 GB
- 56.7 GB + 1.7 GB + 3.1 GB = 61.5 GB

There's a very good answer to a similar question, [Reserved space for root on a filesystem - why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why), which explains the reasoning behind this reservation. It also gives a command that will reduce the reservation percentage, but I would strongly advise you not to change it unless you understand and accept the problems this may give you later on.

Comment: `SSD`: Using a solid-state drive **fragmentation** is not an issue, but you should use only 75% of the entire drives capacity to have a good balance between performance consistency and capacity.

Comment: @MichaelD interesting. Do you have a reference for the 75% bit?

Comment: here: http://www.howtogeek.com/165542/why-solid-state-drives-slow-down-as-you-fill-them-up/ (see **Benchmark Evidence** paragraph)