# Separate /home partition on arch-based distros take more space than used

Tags: arch-linux, partition, home, storage

```
/dev/dm-1 861G 325M 817G 1% /home
```

I have a separate luks encrypted `/home` partition with 861G allocated out of a 931G HDD.

The usage is around 1%, but the availabe space is **only 817G**.

I am having this problem with multiple Arch-based distros like Manjaro, Antergos. I reported this on their forums, but couldn't find a solution yet. They concluded this might be a problem with inode configuration. So I think this must be a problem irrespective of distros.

Is it possible to configure a separate `/home` partition on a 1TB HDD?

Why is the reported available space only 817G out of allocated 861G?

Comment: Which file-system do you use?

Comment: EXT4 on a /home partition.

Answer (score 0):

It is common to reserve some of the blocks for root, and those are not counted as "available" in df's output. If your filesystem has 5% of reserved blocks and is 861GB, there is 95% of that left, or about 817GB, which is consistent with what you see.

This U+L question may be relevant: [Reserved space for root on a filesystem - why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why)

Comment: Thanks I figured it out and EXT4 reserves 5% of partition for root privileges and so to avoid fragmentation and other issues.

Comment: with my previous comment, here I was driving at!