# Disk Space Available but shows 100% Full

Tags: rhel, disk-usage

I am checking the space on one RHEL Server

```
/dev/mapper/vg_db-LogVol01
                      754G  716G   53M 100% /u001
```

I even restarted the server and with no APP or DB running still space is not released.

```
lsof |grep -i deleted
```

shows nothing.

## INodes Usage

```
/dev/mapper/vg_db-LogVol01              48M   54K   48M    1% /u001
```

Comment: FS is ext3 , and for iNodes it shows 48M   54K   48M    1% /u001

Comment: Does https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7950/117549 help any?

Comment: @JeffSchaller no it seems not as i there are other server which some time reach 99% but still shows space available

Comment: Is your question about why 53 mb free is showing as 100% vs 99%? Or that 53mb is not what you expect for free space?

Comment: My question is where in Linux world 38GB gone ;) this happened to me 3-4 times before but normally after restarting the DB or Server itself this issue was resolved. But this time it's strange

Comment: I had an hdd showing similar symptoms. I think it was failing. Have you tried checking the disk ? `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdx` displays for you some failing values ? you can also launch a full smart test with `smartctl` (takes hours runs in the background)

Comment: also , have you searched for big files/folders ? some app might have left 38gb of junk somewhere