# Why 576GB of files on ext4 doesn't fit on a 600GB xfs?

Tags: rsync, disk-usage, ext4, xfs

I want to test XFS dedup feature, so i put a new HD to my fileserver VM.
I started rsync files from old disk to new one, but I got "No space left on device".

This is my `df -h` output:

```
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/debian7-root   982G  576G  356G  62% /
/dev/mapper/owncloud-data  600G  600G  181M 100% /mnt/owncloud-data
```

I want to copy /var/www/owncloud/data/ (inside / disk)

```
du -sh /var/www/owncloud/data/
571G    /var/www/owncloud/data/
```

to `/dev/mapper/owncloud-data`.

I typed (when `/dev/mapper/owncloud-data` was empty)

```
rsync -av --progress /var/www/owncloud/data/*  /mnt/owncloud-data/
```

but I got "no space left on device".

So, why can't I fit 576GB of data on a 600GB disk?

Updated: maybe it isn't clear, but destination disk 600GB is XFS formatted, so there isn't any 5% reserved space.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reserved space for root on a filesystem - why?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why)

Comment: 5% of the space on ext4 is reserved for root by default, and 5% of 600 GB is 30 GB.

Comment: @muru 600GB is XFS not ext4

Comment: Hmm, in that case, try the `xfs_check` command to see if space is overallocated somewhere

Answer (score 7):

I've solved it: in the source data there is 47GB of files hardlinked. 
Now I'm trying rsync with -H option, I can see at start of rsync it has freed 70GB of data hard linking a lot of files.

Thank you