# df shows 100% used, but logs keep getting written

Tags: logs, disk-usage

We have a system we're trying to fault test. The scenario I'm running involves simulating a full disk (our attached logger disk to be specific). I've filled the disk using `df -h` to see how much space is left (so assume 4G for this example) and then `sudo fallocate -l 10G /opt/var/big.file` to generate a file up to the limit.

When I do `df` I do see that `Use%` is 100% and `Available` is 0. However, if I go to my log directory I see things like:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 0  28M Nov  7 17:43 service.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 0 4.0K Nov  7 17:43 service.log-2017-11-07-17-13.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 0 1.2K Nov  7 17:43 service.log-2017-11-07-17-14.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 0  27M Nov  7 17:44 service.log-2017-11-07-17-15
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 0    0 Nov  7 17:44 service.log-2017-11-07-17-15.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 0 1.3K Nov  7 17:40 service.log-2017-11-07-17-1.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 0  28M Nov  7 17:41 service.log-2017-11-07-17-2
-rw-r--r-- 1 0 0 4.0K Nov  7 17:41 service.log-2017-11-07-17-3
```

If I `tail -f service.log` I can see that data is being appended. I can also see that my `log4j2` settings are rotating files appropriately (although several files show as unzipped until sometime later). Once a file finishes zipping up, logs are appended to the end of the active log file. It's like we're writing to the log so fast (DEBUG logging is turned on, which write about 40M of log per second, and the rotate max size is set to 200M) that it can't fully zip the files before getting requested to zip another file... or something like that.

I'm not sure what to make of this - could someone help shed some light?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default 5% of the volume space is [reserved for root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why) on format. There is no more user space on the volume, but the logs are being written by root.

Comment: Can I force this 5% to be simulated as full somehow?

Comment: Fill it as root.

Comment: I did - I'll update my command above, but it was ran as `sudo`

Comment: You didn't fill it enough.

Comment: I'm not super convinced yet. It's a 100G disk, it had 4G free (reported), I attempted to allocate a 10G file (which should have allocated the 4G + 5% (5G) from room right?). What am I missing?

Comment: That it's still not full.

Comment: You're right, but is there a way I can see _real_ availability? If I do `sudo df` it still just shows the same output, with no indication of what's available from that 5%

Comment: AFAIK not really. You just compare the total to used until they're equal. Omitting `-h` can help with that.

Comment: Brute force filler: `sudo  dd if=/dev/zero of=waste.of.space bs=1M`.  Laggy what's-really-left for ext-based filesystems: `sync; sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sda2`.

Comment: You can adjust the reserved space with tunefs, but there are performance implications you should consider first: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why