# Volume show different sizes in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, lvm, size, parted

I hope you and your dears are very well.

I'm facing a issue which I cannot understand the root cause.

I have a VM with CentOS 7 64 bits. This VM has the following partitions:

```
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cl-root  1.1T  1.1T  3.1G 100% /
devtmpfs             126G     0  126G   0% /dev
tmpfs                126G     0  126G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                126G  4.1G  122G   4% /run
tmpfs                126G     0  126G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3            239M  147M   76M  66% /boot
/dev/mapper/cl-tmp   190M  1.6M  175M   1% /tmp
tmpfs                 26G     0   26G   0% /run/user/0
```

In the mount point `/` (root), as you can see I have just 3.1 GB available of a volume total size 1.1 TB.

I tried to identify if there is some delete file locked by some process, but this is not the case:

```
# ls -l /proc/*/fd/* | grep deleted
ls: cannot access /proc/20484/fd/255: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /proc/20484/fd/3: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /proc/self/fd/255: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /proc/self/fd/3: No such file or directory
```

Using `parted`, I find that this partition has the following size:

```
#parted /dev/cl/root
GNU Parted 3.1
Using /dev/dm-0
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print free
Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/dm-0: 1197GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
1   0.00B  1197GB  **1197GB**  ext4
```

Using `lvdisplay` to check the logical volume, I have:

```
# lvdisplay /dev/mapper/cl-root
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/cl/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                cl
  LV UUID                hwPnR8-7VX2-DNjb-HUjU-Cbai-Rl37-txslGH
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time computer-node-07, 2018-10-17 13:59:48 -0300
  LV Status              available
  #open                  1
  LV Size                1.09 TiB
  Current LE             285364
  Segments               10
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  -currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0
```

Now, when I get the volume size using `du`, I had the following output:

```
du -csh --block-size=1G /Mb
du: cannot access ‘/proc/173159/task/173159/fd/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/173159/task/173159/fdinfo/3’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/173159/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/173159/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
1049
1049    total
```

I also tried to find whether there is a available space in the Volume Group, but I don't have:

```
# vgdisplay -v cl|grep Free
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  Total PE / Free PE    285414 / 0
```

Could you help me to understand this situation?

Thanks.
Cardoso

Answer (score 0):

The reported size from the tools seems to be the same. You have a `1.09 TiB` root logical volume, `df` output is rounded and parted shows `1197 GB` which is `1.09 TiB`.

The "missing" free space is the filesystem reserved space. It's by default 5 % on ext4. You can check number of reserved blocks in `dumpe2fs`. You can change the reserve size using `tune2fs -m <size> <device>`, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why) for more details about reserved space on ext4.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Regarding the reserverd blocks (5% on ext4), in this case I should be available 1137GB and the file system root (/) has only 1052GB a deficit of 88GB.Regarding the tool dumpe2fs, I had the following output: ```# dumpe2fs -h /dev/sda5
dumpe2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda5
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.```I tried to use other options, like -b, but I received the same output.

Comment: 95 % of 1.09 TiB is 1060.35 GiB so with 3.1 GiB free and `du` reporting 1049 GiB you are missing only 8.25 GiB (`lvdisplay`, `df` and `du` report sizes in binary units not decimal) which is less than 1 % and is probably used by journal and other metadata.
You need to use `dumpe2fs /dev/mapper/cl-root`, `/dev/sda5` is the LVM partition, not the ext4 root logical volume.